# Which ssd configuration is best for programming using Visual Studio 2019? 2 SSD 1TB with RAID 0 configuration or one single SSD 2TB

Tags: ssd, raid, windows-11, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I want to buy a DELL machine of 17". I have two options:

- DELL [Alienware x17](https://www.dell.com/es-es/shop/port%C3%A1tiles-dell/alienware-x17/spd/alienware-x17-r2-laptop/nawx17r203)
  Intel Core i7 12700H 12th generation, Windows 11 PRO (English & Spanish),  Graphic Card NVIDIA
  GeForce RTX 3070 Ti 8GB,  RAM DDR5 32 GB,  SSD 2 TB,  Screen UHD 17.3” 3840x2160,  Spanish
  Keyboard.
- DELL [XPS 17](https://www.dell.com/es-es/shop/port%C3%A1tiles-dell/nuevo-xps-17/spd/xps-17-9720-laptop/cn97204cc)
  Intel Core i7 12700H 12th generation, Windows 11 PRO (English & Spanish),  Graphic Card NVIDIA
  GeForce RTX 3060 6GB,  RAM DDR5 32 GB,  SSD 2 TB,  Screen UHD+ 17.0” 3840x2400,  Spanish
  Keyboard.

I think the best is DELL Alienware (what do you think?) and in this case there is the possibility to buy it with a RAID 0 configuration (2 x SSD 1TB) or a single SSD 2TB (without RAID-0).

What is best? with RAID 0 configuration or without? and why?

I have heard that using RAID 0 there is a risk of loosing data, if one disk fails, you lose. But this is the same as having 1 single SSD without RAID 0 I think, If this disk fails you also lose. or not? is not the same problem as having a failure in a RAID 0 configuration?

Also I think RAID-0 you can access files in parallel so I think it affects the compilation process under Visual Studio which is fast with RAID-0 I think. What do you think?

Also RAID 0 is compatible with Visual Studio?

So for programming it is worth a RAID 0 or better to not use RAID 0?

Answer (score 1):

**RAID0**:
RAID partitions are just seen by your OS (and all the software on it) as a regular drive, so yeah, that should work. I doubt that performance wise you'd need two SSDs in RAID0 though, unless you're doing *extremely* heavy I/O (which is probably not the case here, more of a server thing). **I would really go with the single 2TB drive.**

**Failure:**
Yes, two SSDs in RAID0 doubles your chances of losing your data. There are two devices, each with an *independent* chance to fail. Failure of one means losing the entire partition. And SMART status (*"drive health"*) does not predict all failures, a good amount of these just happens without warning.

**Backups:**
Note that in all cases, RAID or not, keeping regular backups is very strongly recommended. File recovery tends to be prohibitively expensive. You don't have to back up everything and equally frequent, but I would consider making sure your most important and/or most frequently changing files are covered. The rest according to budget.

Answer (score 0):

The single 2tb disk is likely a better choice - it will gave more wear cycles (because its overprovisioned more), will facilitate future expansion, use less power and be easier to set up.

The only disadvantage is speed of SSD access -  but NMVE SSD is blazingly fast - and often larger SSDs are faster then smaller ones because they can do more in parellel. (ie they behave rather like RAID0 internally anyway).

The alienware system has better graphics if you are going to be gaming - and likely better expandability - but its also likely to be heavier and a less premium finish compared to an XPS.  The former line is targetted at gamers, the latter at business professionals with money to burn.

If you are doing coding the extra pixels on the XPS might be nice.

RAID0 is not backup, and if you dint know what it is, avoid it here - it adds complexity and risk.  On the other hand, RAID1 - which would provide you with 2 copies if the data can protect against a single SSD failure and may be worthwhile **but it is not a backup, it only protects agains ssd failure** and halves the available disk space - in the above case to 1tb.